# smartyのforeachで表示する複数の情報の表示個数をそれぞれ別に指定したいです。

Tags: php, smarty

あるアプリケーションを使用し、情報表示サイトを作成しております。その新着情報ブロックでのphp、smartyに関するご質問でございます。

そのブロックは新たに登録された情報を6つまで表示する内容のもので、phpでその表示の個数を指定し、smartyでforeachを使用して表示させております。問題はその新着情報が6つ表示された段階で“新着情報の一覧を見る”という新着情報一覧ページへ誘導させるリンクボタンを表示させたいのですが、その新着情報一覧のurlも以下の様に配列を使用したものになりよってforeach内に配置しなければなりません。ということは6個のボタンが表示されることになりますが、このボタンを一つだけ表示させたい場合どう対処すれば宜しいかお教え願いませんでしょうか。

```
<!--{foreach from=$arrProducts item=arrProduct}-->

(新着情報)
<h3><a href="<!--{$smarty.const.P_DETAIL_URLPATH}--><!--     {$arrProduct.product_id|u}-->&<!--{$smarty.const.CATEGORY_URLPATH}--><!--{$arrProduct.category_name_e|u}-->"><!--{$arrProduct.name|h}--></a></h3>

(新着情報一覧ページボタン)
<a href="http://xxxx/products/list.php?category_name=<!--{$arrProduct.category_name|h}-->&mode=search&category_id=9"><!--{$arrProduct.category_name|h}-->一覧</a>

<!--{/foreach}-->
```

Comment: 配列要素からURLを生成する場合それぞれのURLが異なる可能性があるので、6つ表示されるのは真っ当に見えます。その中で一つだけ表示したいということですが、同じURLが生成されることが保証されているのか、どれか一つを適当に選べばよいのか、その辺りを質問を編集して追記していただけませんか？

Answer (score 1):

大変失礼いたしました。

同じphpファイル内にそれぞれプログラム箇所を二つに分け、smartyのforeachも二つに分けることでとりあえず機能している様です。おさがわせ致しました。